# Composer interpreting Tildes

Tags: php, composer-php

How is the tilde interpreted?
An example is

```
"require":{
  symfony/config": "~2.3"
}
```

Does that mean chose the closest version to 2.3 either up or down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the documentation: http://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#package-versions

> Next Significant Release (Tilde Operator): The ~ operator is best explained by example: 
>   `~1.2` is equivalent to `>=1.2,<2.0`, while `~1.2.3` is equivalent to `>=1.2.3,<1.3`

It'll install at least that required version, but not a version that increments the next bigger bit of the version number.